# Subscript out of range when using a public declared array in a different private subroutine

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, public

I have assigned a refedit selected range to an array called `dataarray0` I have declared it as public and then use this array in the main subroutine. However, when I run from the Private sub through to the main subroutine, I get `subscript out of range` error  which I just can't  figure out. Please find below two codes 1 is the code for the USERFORM that defines the array and 2 the code which uses this array:

```
Option Explicit
Public dataarray0 As Variant

Private Sub ActiWorkBook_Change()
   If ActiWorkBook <> "" Then Application.Workbooks(ActiWorkBook.Text).Activate
   Label1.Caption = "": RefEdit1 = ""
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Dim addr As String, partderivrng As Range, cell As Range, thisbook As String, NROWSPDIV As Integer
   Dim NCOLSPDIV As Integer
   Dim mydestination As Range
   Dim dataarray0() As Variant, DEST As Variant


   If RefEdit1.Value = "" Then
      Partderiv.Hide
      ERR1.Show
   Else
      addr = RefEdit1.Value
      Set partderivrng = Range(addr)
      NROWSPDIV = Range(addr).Rows.Count
      NCOLSPDIV = Range(addr).Columns.Count
'      ReDim dataarray0(NROWSPDIV, NCOLSPDIV)
      dataarray0() = partderivrng
      ThisWorkbook.Activate
      Sheets("PD").Select
      Set mydestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
          "What is the first cell in the destination range for data?", Type:=8)
      mydestination.Select

'      mydestination.Paste Link:=True
      Partderiv.Hide

      Set DEST = mydestination.Resize(NROWSPDIV, NCOLSPDIV)
      DEST.Value = dataarray0

   End If
   Data1.Show
   End
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload Me
DYNA1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   Dim wb As Workbook

   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
      ActiWorkBook.AddItem wb.Name
   Next

   ActiWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
   Partderiv.RefEdit1.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
   Label1.Caption = ""
   If RefEdit1.Value <> "" Then _
   Label1.Caption = "[" & ActiWorkBook & "]" & RefEdit1
End Sub
```

```
Sub CALC1_Run(ByRef dataarray1 As Variant, ByRef dataarray0 As Variant)
' This subroutine runs the calculation for the Isolated brick: Simple KWR Strength Calculation
' Created 27/11/2019 by Owen Booler
' Version 1: 27/11/2019 - Creation of subroutine  by Owen Booler
'Integer definitions
' Loop Identifiers
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
' Other Variables
Dim NSIM As Integer, NSITES As Integer, NKWRS As Integer, NTIME As Integer, NHITS As Integer

' Double Precision definitions
' String definitions
Dim DIST As String

' Array definitions
Dim Prob() As Double, SAMPSTRENGTH() As Double, SDV23 As Double, IRRSAMPSTRENGTH() As Variant
Dim NEWARRAY() As Variant, HITTIME() As Double
' Range definitions
Dim DEST1 As Range, DEST2 As Range



Randomize

' Defintions for Testing
NSIM = 1000
DIST = "N"
NTIME = Val(DYNA1.NUMTINC) + 2
' Real definitions

'NSIM = Val(MCINPUT1.NUMSIM)
'DIST = Val(MCINPUT1.DSTRENGTH)
NSITES = 16 ' Number of cracking sites
NKWRS = 16
'Re define arrays to match size of number of simulations
ReDim SAMPSTRENGTH(NSIM, NKWRS), Prob(NSIM, NKWRS), IRRSAMPSTRENGTH(NSIM, NKWRS)
ReDim NEWARRAY(2, NKWRS)
ReDim HITTIME(NTIME)
'NEWARRAY = Array(Data1.dataarray1)
For i = 1 To NSIM

   ' Calculate Sample Strength
   If DIST = "N" Then

      For j = 1 To NKWRS
         HITTIME(0) = 0
         NHITS = 0
         Prob(i, j) = Rnd()
         SAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) = sabNORMINV(Prob(i, j), 27.5653, 1.1777)
'        SAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) = sabNORMINV(Prob, Val(MCINPUT1.MSTRENGTH), Val(MCINPUT1.SSTRENGTH))


         IRRSAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) = SAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) * dataarray1(2, j + 1)
         For k = 1 To NTIME
' Maybe put a check in here to see whether keyway root are the same in stress and strength
            If dataarray0(k + 2, j + 1) > IRRSAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) Then
               NHITS = NHITS + 1
               HITTIME(k) = dataarray0(k + 2, 1)
            Else
               HITTIME(k) = HITTIME(k - 1)
            End If
            If HITTIME(k) = 0 Then
               GoTo 10
            ElseIf HITTIME(k) < HITTIME(k - 1) Then
               HITTIME(j) = HITTIME(k)
            Else
            End If
10       Next
      Next
   Else
      MsgBox "ERROR - VALUE FOR DISTRIBUTION NOT RECOGNISED"
      End
   End If
Next
Set DEST1 = Sheets("Sample").Range("B2").Resize(NSIM + 1, NKWRS + 1)
Set DEST2 = Sheets("Data").Range("B10").Resize(NSIM + 1, NKWRS + 1)
DEST1.Value = IRRSAMPSTRENGTH
DEST2.Value = SAMPSTRENGTH



End Sub
```

Comment: To add, the error occurs at ``` If dataarray0(k + 2, j + 1) > IRRSAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) Then```

Comment: In your sub, your are defining an new array `Dim dataarray0() As Variant, DEST As Variant`. This new array is the one use in the Sub, not the public one defined above, and it does not have the same scope.

Comment: Remove the additional definition in the Sub.

Comment: @VincentG Thanks, but when I do as you suggest removing ```Dim dataarray0()``` as variant, it comes up with another error earlier in the process now in the first code at ```dataarray0()=partderivrng``` error is also subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0):

The Public variable `dataarray0` declared in the module is not modified in the Sub `CommandButton2_Click` because you also defined a local variable with the same name in the sub.

Hence all access to `dataarray0` in the Sub are made on the local defined variable, not the global public one. And when trying to access the variable from another place, you are accessing an uninitialized Variant.

If it is not useful, remove the local unneeded local variable which is masking the global one.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Dim addr As String, partderivrng As Range, cell As Range, thisbook As String, NROWSPDIV As Integer
   Dim NCOLSPDIV As Integer
   Dim mydestination As Range
   'Dim dataarray0() As Variant, DEST As Variant
   Dim DEST As Variant
  .
  .
  .
End Sub
```

---

Edit:
In your current code, the public declaration is:

`Public dataarray0 As Variant`

A variant can contain an array, so the syntax `dataarray0 = partdelivery` will assign the content of the range to the variable, which will then become of type Variant/Variant array
[image]
[image]
And you will access data like this:[image]

You won't be able to declare dataarray0 as an array of Variant like this, at least not at module scope:

`Public dataarray0() As Variant 'WRONG -> compile error`

Comment: Thanks, However, when doing this, the error ```subscript out of range``` now resides with ```dataarray0()=partderivrng```

Comment: `dataarray0` is not defined as an array, but as a Variant... so there is no dataarray0() (yet). Either change the definition to an array of Variant, or initialize the value with `dataarray0 = partdelivery` (in which case it will be a Variant containing an array)

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by this, ```partdelivrng``` is a range and I thought that in order to assign a range to an array you need the () at the end.  How when this is called in the module does it know it is 2d array with subscript k and j?

Comment: Thanks and sorry to be a pain, but now after applying that in the module it comes up with subscript out of range at ```If dataarray0(k + 2, j + 1) > IRRSAMPSTRENGTH(i, j) Then``` so back to the beginning.

Comment: What are the values of the Lbounds and Ubounds of the arrays, and the values of k, j and i  when it fails? It should indicate where the error lie.

Comment: I have solved this issue now thanks! Please see the answer I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that because `dataarray0` is declared as public in a `userform` that it doesn't behave as a global variable and therefore when I use it in my module I should put the userform name prior to the use of dataarray0 i.e.

`Partderiv.dataarray0` this seems to now work

Thanks